# Is filesystemwatcher the right way to monitor a file?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I know it’s a general question but I’m just opening this for discussion.  I have to assume someone else must have done similar and I don’t want to do a lot of code to find out my solution wouldn’t work.

Here's what I have.  A user will add a file to the database as an OLE object and associate some attitude to the file - project it's associated to, version etc.  I’m using Access – customer choice not mine!

When they want to edit it, they will need to check it out.  At this stage I want to monitor the file and when they save it, to restore it back to the database.

I'm thinking that file system watcher is my best way - monitor the change and save it back to the database when the change even is triggered and I can gain access to the file.  If it's still opened the application will have it locked so I know that the user isn’t finish.

So in short my question is file system watcher the proper way to approach this?  Anyone suggest anything else?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: do you mean the user will add a record to the database..? if so write a simple query.. or are they adding their own access db file..? if so FileWatacher at the Create and or Modify properties can be checked / accessed.. please be more specific as well for clarification

Comment: @DJKRAZE - The user will be adding records to the database part of which will be the physical file either as an OLE object or attactment.  When they "check out" the file from the database to work on it, this is when I need to monitor it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As M4GNV5 says, `FileSystemWatcher` will work for this but it's a bit overkill. Using one is pretty involved in code as it's quite error-prone and needs very exact usage patterns to be successful. It also has a certain amount of overhead as it needs to hook into the filesystem driver in kernel mode.

An alternate solution might use polling.

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);
DateTime oldTime = info.LastWriteTimeUtc;

while(true)
{
    do
    {
        await Task.Wait(1000);
        info.Refresh();
    } while(info.LastWriteTimeUtc == oldTime);

    try
    {
        using(Stream s = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            // ok, file was modified and is unlocked. copy back.
        }

        break;
    }
    catch(IOException)
    {
        // file is locked, retry.
        oldTime = info.LastWriteTimeUtc;
    }
}
```

This first waits for the file's modify time to change, and then checks for it to be unlocked.

Comment: Thank you that seems a simpler over all approach!  Glad I asked before I ran head first into file system watch.  Where I believe I would have gotten it working, I think it might have taken a lot of development and support time to sort through all the issues.

Comment: I have some code for it using the Rx framework if you're interested. Makes it a little easier but still not simple. https://idcomlog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IdComLog.Reactive/FileSystem.cs

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to monitor a single file or a directory?

FileSystemWatcher was designed to watch Directories as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx tells you

So in order to monitor a single File FileSystemWatcher could be OP
but in order to monitor a whole directory its defnitly the right choice

Comment: So what would you suggest for monitoring a single file?

Comment: I think that depends on the Problem. Tim said the files are locked as long as the user edit them so in my opinion the best approach would be to set up an timer and try to open the file in write mode every x seconds and see if its still locked

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor a single file. You can set the Filter property to be the specific file you are interested in. Or set it to *.mdb (or similar) and compare the FileSystemEventArgs path to only do something if the Change event is for the file you have interest in.

Pseudo code:

- When they check out the file, create it on the file system and create a file system watcher with a Filter matching the file and subscribe to the Changed event
- In the Changed event, check if you can access the file, i.e. whether the lock is released, and if so do whatever it is you want to do

Is this the best solution? Really depends on several factors. Can they save in-progress work, thus leaving the file locked, then exit without saving again? If so you would not get a second Changed event.

Crude as it is, polling (checking the status of the file on a timer and whether the last modified attribute has changed) might be a better solution.

Comment: thank you, Cory Nelson has suggested the same approach. This is exactly why I posted the question here before I ran head first into file system watcher!

Answer (score 0):

What if they click save within the application, but don't close it? The file could still be locked and unreadable even after the watcher reports a change was made, but it depends on the editor.

Another way is to launch the editing application directly yourself and monitor the process to see when the user closes the application, although this can have problems with tabbed editors which opening more than one document in the same proccess.

So for reliability, apps like FTP clients normally use a timed loop and monitor the file size and date modified properties for changes, then action the file.

Something to be aware of is you may need a delay before taking action as virus scanners can also lock and scan files after a change has taken place preventing your code from having immediate access.

Comment: @WholsRich - the problem with lauching the editing application is that it might be any app.  There is no restriction on what file the user can check into the database so it might be work, excel, an image etc.

Comment: Then a loop check is a sensible choice, just keep in mind ways the logic could break, some apps don't hold a lock during editing, people may switch between apps, how will opening multiple files work, old office machines may be slow, with a delay between the lastWrite being updated and the file being released, etc.

Comment: yep I was thinking more or less the same myself but lucky enough I have experience with apps that are required to be running 24/7.